# Compile Error : Syntax Error - MS ACCESS 2007 on SQL INSERT INTO Statement

Tags: ms-access, syntax

I am attempting to create the following SQL INSERT INTO statement, but I am getting a Syntax Error. Any suggestions?:

```
SQL = "
INSERT INTO AptRent 
    (BuildingID,
     RentAmountID, 
     InitialRentDueDate, 
     TenantID, 
     AptNoID, 
     MoveInDate, 
     MoveOutDate,  
     DateAdded, 
     SecurityAmount, 
     SecurityPaid, 
     NoDaysLate, 
     LateAmount) 
    VALUES
    (" & Me.cbSelectBuildingForRental & "," 
       & Me.cbCreateRentalRentAmount & "," 
       & Me.tbCreateRentalRDD & "," 
       & Me.cbSelectTenantForRental & ", '" 
       & Me.cbSelectAptNoforRental & "' ," 
       & Me.tbCreateRentalMID & "," 
       & Me.tbCreateRentalMOD & "," 
       & Now() & "," 
       & Me.tbSecurityAmnt & "," 
       & Me.ckSecurityPd & "," 
       & Me.tbNoDaysLate & "," 
       & Me.tbLatePmnt & ")"
```

Table **AptRent** has the following data types:

*BuildingRentID*: AutoNumber

*BuildingID*: Number (**Me.cbSelectBuildingForRental**)

*RentAmountID*: Number (**Me.cbCreateRentalRentAmount**)

*InitialRentDueDate*: Date/Time (**Me.tbCreateRentalRDD**)

*TenantID*: Number (**Me.cbSelectTenantForRental**)

*AptNoID*: Text (**Me.cbSelectAptNoforRental**)

*MoveInDate*: Date/Time (**Me.tbCreateRentalMID**)

*MoveOutDate*: Date/Time (**Me.tbCreateRentalMOD**)

*DateAdded*: Date/Time (**Now()**)

*SecurityAmount*: Currency (**Me.tbSecurityAmnt**)

*SecurityPaid*: Yes/No (**Me.ckSecurityPd**)

*NoDaysLate*: Number (**Me.tbNoDaysLate**)

*LateAmount:* Currency (**Me.tbLatePmnt**)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're ISO formatted (YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS), you need to add single quotes around your Date/Time values.

```
...
& "'" & Me.tbCreateRentalMID & "', " 
...
```

and so on for all of your Date/Time columns.

Comment: Actually, since he's using ms-access. He'll want to use # instead of '.

Comment: @DanielCook: I believe single quotes will work *when the value is ISO formatted*, which I stated in my assumption. Otherwise, you are correct.

Comment: I think it depends on what "engine" he's using to run this statement. If it's DAO or ODBC Linked Tables (which is also DAO) then he will need hash signs. I believe ADO also requires hash signs although I'm not perfectly sure on that. In any case, he certainly does need something around the date values.